# Jupyter notebook matplotlib figures show up small until cell is completed

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to make a notebook where the data produced by a long for loop is put in a graph point by point. However, when using `%matplotlib notebook` and `fig.canvas.draw()` the graph is tiny up until the cell finishes running. (In fact, I've got many of those graphs and they are even tinyer when using more subplots.)

Here my code reproducing the behaviour in a jupyter notebook, at least on OS X with (latest) jupyter-core 4.3.0 and (latest) matplotlib 2.0.2.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
for _ in range(5):
    ax.plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
    fig.canvas.draw()
    time.sleep(1)
```

During the cell execution I get this plot

[image: Small image]

And when the cell finishes execution (after 5 seconds) I get this

[image]

I would like to get the larger image even during cell execution. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When I run the code the plot does not change size (python 2.7, jupyter 4.4.1, matplotlib 2.0.2). I therefore cannot test if it makes a difference, but try to put the for loop in a new cell. That way the figure is first created in its full size and only in the next cell the animation goes on. Also note that in order to do animations with matplotlib, you may use the `FuncAnimation`.

Comment: I got the exact same issue with `%matplotlib widget` inside JupyterLab :/

Answer (score 2):

As proposed by ImportanceOfBeingErnest, one solution is to put the figure creation in its own cell.

```
[1] %matplotlib notebook
    import time
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

[2] fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

[3] for _ in range(5):
        ax.plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
        fig.canvas.draw()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Edit: This solutions does not work if you run all cells at once.

Comment: I'll try to bring this issue to the `matplotlib` developers. I need to use this function over and over, I keep Googling it, and fail to find how to properly do so.